# Dcast only one variable into a new column R

Tags: r, data.table, melt, dcast

I'm trying to `dcast` my data so that I can split out only the `Actual` values into a new column. However, the only way that I've managed to do this is to `dcast` and then `melt` back. I was wondering if there's a more efficient solution.

**Step 1:**

I've done a little prep for my data, but this is what it looks like:

```
> test_m <- melt(test, id.vars = c("category", "Budget_year", "State"))
> test_m <- test_m[,c("Year", "Type_of_observation"):= tstrsplit(variable, " ", fixed = TRUE)]
> test_m[,variable := NULL]
> head(test_m, n = 10)

          category Budget_year State value    Year Type_of_observation
 1:  Transfer Duty     2000_01     N  1916 1998-99              Actual
 2:       Land Tax     2000_01     N   948 1998-99              Actual
 3:    Payroll Tax     2000_01     N  3605 1998-99              Actual
 4: Total Gambling     2000_01     N  1419 1998-99              Actual
 5:            GST     2000_01     N  4705 1998-99              Actual
 6:  Transfer Duty     2000_01     N  1747 1999-00              Budget
 7:       Land Tax     2000_01     N   830 1999-00              Budget
 8:    Payroll Tax     2000_01     N  3616 1999-00              Budget
 9: Total Gambling     2000_01     N  1558 1999-00              Budget
10:            GST     2000_01     N  5162 1999-00              Budget
```

Now I want to make a new column out of the `Type_of_observation` column, but only taking the `Actual` observations and leaving all the other observation types behind. My current method is to `dcast` and then `melt`, as follows:

**Step 2: Desired output**

```
> test_c <- dcast(test_m, category + Budget_year + State + Year ~ Type_of_observation)
> test_mc <- melt(test_c, id.vars = c("category", "Budget_year", "State", "Year", "Actual"), measure.vars = c("Budget", "Estimate", "Revised"))
> head(test_mc, n = 10)
    category Budget_year State    Year Actual variable value
 1:      GST     2000_01     N 1998-99   4705   Budget    NA
 2:      GST     2000_01     N 1999-00     NA   Budget  5162
 3:      GST     2000_01     N 2000-01     NA   Budget  8318
 4:      GST     2000_01     N 2001-02     NA   Budget    NA
 5:      GST     2000_01     N 2002-03     NA   Budget    NA
 6:      GST     2000_01     N 2003-04     NA   Budget    NA
 7: Land Tax     2000_01     N 1998-99    948   Budget    NA
 8: Land Tax     2000_01     N 1999-00     NA   Budget   830
 9: Land Tax     2000_01     N 2000-01     NA   Budget   921
10: Land Tax     2000_01     N 2001-02     NA   Budget    NA
```

So now i've got a column for `Actuals` and all the other types of observations are left in the `variable` column.

Is there a way that i can go from `test_m` to `test_mc` without having to do both `dcast` and `melt`? I'm preferably after a `data.table` solution, but am open to anything.

Here's the `dput` for `test_m`:

```
> dput(test_m)
structure(list(category = c("Transfer Duty", "Land Tax", "Payroll Tax", 
"Total Gambling", "GST", "Transfer Duty", "Land Tax", "Payroll Tax", 
"Total Gambling", "GST", "Transfer Duty", "Land Tax", "Payroll Tax", 
"Total Gambling", "GST", "Transfer Duty", "Land Tax", "Payroll Tax", 
"Total Gambling", "GST", "Transfer Duty", "Land Tax", "Payroll Tax", 
"Total Gambling", "GST", "Transfer Duty", "Land Tax", "Payroll Tax", 
"Total Gambling", "GST", "Transfer Duty", "Land Tax", "Payroll Tax", 
"Total Gambling", "GST"), Budget_year = c("2000_01", "2000_01", 
"2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", 
"2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", 
"2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", 
"2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", 
"2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01", 
"2000_01", "2000_01", "2000_01"), State = c("N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), value = c("1916", "948", "3605", "1419", 
"4705", "1747", "830", "3616", "1558", "5162", "2249", "889", 
"3742", "1578", "5173", "1746", "921", "3931", "1212", "8318", 
"1686", "948", "4146", "1241", "9520", "1756", "971", "4258", 
"1309", "9789", "1904", "991", "4503", "1374", "10006"), Year = c("1998-99", 
"1998-99", "1998-99", "1998-99", "1998-99", "1999-00", "1999-00", 
"1999-00", "1999-00", "1999-00", "1999-00", "1999-00", "1999-00", 
"1999-00", "1999-00", "2000-01", "2000-01", "2000-01", "2000-01", 
"2000-01", "2001-02", "2001-02", "2001-02", "2001-02", "2001-02", 
"2002-03", "2002-03", "2002-03", "2002-03", "2002-03", "2003-04", 
"2003-04", "2003-04", "2003-04", "2003-04"), Type_of_observation = c("Actual", 
"Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Budget", "Budget", "Budget", 
"Budget", "Budget", "Revised", "Revised", "Revised", "Revised", 
"Revised", "Budget", "Budget", "Budget", "Budget", "Budget", 
"Estimate", "Estimate", "Estimate", "Estimate", "Estimate", "Estimate", 
"Estimate", "Estimate", "Estimate", "Estimate", "Estimate", "Estimate", 
"Estimate", "Estimate", "Estimate")), .Names = c("category", 
"Budget_year", "State", "value", "Year", "Type_of_observation"
), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x026c24a0>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can complete the cases first, and then join with your dataset.

Finally, you do an update join to lookup the Actual values.

```
#create complete cases
ans <- test_m[CJ(category=category, Budget_year=Budget_year, State=State, Year=Year, Type_of_observation=c("Budget", "Estimate", "Revised"), unique=TRUE),
    on=.(category, Budget_year, State, Year, Type_of_observation)][
        #update join
        test_m[Type_of_observation=="Actual"], 
        Actual := i.value,
        on=.(category, Budget_year, State, Year)]

#order to match test_mc
setorder(ans, category, Budget_year, State, Year, Type_of_observation)[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a straightforward `data.table` method to accomplish this, using `setkey` and joining within the brackets.

I'll use a simpler `data.table`. The goal is to get the `interest_rate` into its own column.

```
samp <- data.table(
  group=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"),
  variable=c("balance", "end_balance","interest_rate"),
  value=c(1000, 940, .05, 1200, 1040, .08, 980, 970, .10)
)


setkey(samp, group)

#  This will create a data.table with just our desired variable value, interest_rate, by group
samp[variable=="interest_rate", .(interest_rate=unique(value)), by=.(group)]

#  We then join this to the original data.table using the already set key and
#  drop the interest_rate rows in the final data.table
samp[samp[variable=="interest_rate", .(interest_rate=unique(value)), by=.(group)]][variable!="interest_rate"]
```